# How to fix JSX props should not use .bind() Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component that displays data `onClick` event on a button. Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './cardCheck.css';

class CardCheck extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showMessage: false };
  }

  _showMessage = bool => {
    this.setState({
      showMessage: bool
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this._showMessage.bind(null, true)} />
          </div>
          <div className="results" />
          {this.state.showMessage && (
            <div>
              hello world!
              <button onClick={this._showMessage.bind(null, false)}>hide</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardCheck;
```

The code works, but I have this error in my console:

> JSX props should not use .bind()

I read about it and changed my function to arrow ones like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './cardCheck.css';

class CardCheck extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showMessage: false };
  }

  _showMessage = bool => () => {
    this.setState({
      showMessage: bool
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this._showMessage()} />
          </div>
          <div className="results" />
          {this.state.showMessage && (
            <div>
              hello world!
              <button onClick={this._showMessage()}>hide</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardCheck;
```

The error is gone, but my code does not work now. What is the correct way to do this with arrow functions and still make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either binding or using arrow function [is not suggested](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) since those functions will be recreated in every render. This is why you see those warnings. Instead of binding or invoking with an arrow function use it with reference and change your function a little bit.

```
_showMessage = () =>
    this.setState( prevState => ( { 
       showMessage: !prevState.showMessage,
}) );
```

Instead of using a boolean, we are changing `showMessage` value by using its previous value. Here, we are using `setState` with a function to use previous state since `setState` itself is asynchronous.

And in your element you will use this function with its reference.

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this._showMessage} />
```

Working example.

```js
class CardCheck extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showMessage: false };
  }

  _showMessage = () =>
      this.setState( prevState => ( { 
         showMessage: !prevState.showMessage,
  }) );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="newsletter-container">
          <h1>Enter the ID of your card:</h1>
          <div className="center">
            <input type="number" />
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this._showMessage} />
          </div>
          <div className="results" />
          {this.state.showMessage && (
            <div>
              hello world!
              <button onClick={this._showMessage}>hide</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <h1>Offers:</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <CardCheck />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this._showMessage()} />
```

You are invoking the `_showMessage` function by having the `()` in the `onClick` handler. You just want to pass the reference to the function, i.e. without `()`

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" onClick={this._showMessage} />
```